# iOS 5: Curious about UIAppearance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, appearance

On the tech talk 2011 I saw a speech about the new `UIAppearance` [protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance).  There is not a lot of documentation out there yet. I will shortly summarize what I remember to explain where my question is coming from:

---

**About `UIAppearance`:**

So far you had to customize EVERY navigation bar (toolbar, etc.) property in all your app view controllers. With the new appearance property you can do it in only one place for all navigation bars in your app. For instance: if you want to customize your Navigation bar background image you could do it like this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:
   [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImageName"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

This will set the background image of ALL navigation bars within your application. With the `barMetrics` you specify whether you want the image to be used also in landscape mode or not.

If you want to specify the appearance to be applied only in some view controllers there is also a method in the docs to control that by specifying where your objects are located:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:
    [ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class], nil] setTintColor:myNavBarColor];
```

Also worth to mention is, if you have single customized instances, differing from your appearance settings, theses instances will not be effected by the appearance proxy.

---

**Some questions:**

**a) How do I know which properties of a class work with the appearance property?** For e.g. since `UITableView` conforms to the UIAppearance protocol I was thinking I could do something like

```
[[UITableView appearance] setBackgroundColor:mytableViewColor];
```

to manipulate the background color of all my table views, but I can't!

**b) Is there a list of all classes that are manipulatable with the appearance property?**

**c) At what point is the appearance customization being called?** I was hoping to make changes threw the appearance property at runtime, but unfortunately the changes aren't taking place.

Comment: I asked your question b) here (http://stackoverflow.com/q/9424112/245265) and provided an answer. I did this because I felt that your question title was too general and that no one will be able to find the list that I tediously compiled.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> a) How do I know which instances of a class work with the appearance property? For e.g. since UITableView conforms to the UIAppearance protocol I was thinking I could do something like

You look in the header of the class (and the headers of all the superclasses).  Any method that has `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` next to it is supported for use with the `UIAppearance` proxy.

```
[[UITableView appearance] setBackgroundColor:mytableViewColor];
```

The `backgroundColor` property is not decorated with `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` in `UIView.h`.  Thus it is not technically supported for use with the appearance proxy.  It will *probably* work, but (given the lack of method decoration) isn't guaranteed to.

From the `UIAppearance Protocol Reference`:

> To support appearance customization, a class must conform to the `UIAppearanceContainer` protocol and relevant accessor methods must be marked with `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`.

(note "**and** relevant accessor methods **must** be marked..." [emphasis added])

---

> b) Is there a list of all properties that are manipulatable with the appearance property?

Is there a single page showing every setter that works with the appearance proxy? I don't know of one, nor is there a way to build the list at runtime.

---

> c) At what point is the appearance customization being called? I was hoping to make changes threw the appearance property at runtime, but unfortunately the changes aren't taking place.

You can use the appearance proxy at any point during execution.  The changes won't be applied to the affected views until the next time those views have their `-layoutSubviews` method invoked.

Comment: There's a list of UIAppearance supporting classes now. You can [see it here](http://blog.mosheberman.com/list-of-classes-that-support-uiappearance-in-ios-5/). Might want to update your answer.

Comment: C) I'm experiencing that changes are not applied until the next time -layoutSubviews is applied **In the next run loop**. Anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 3):

`UIAppearance` is documented within the headers of each class. Look within there for methods marked `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` at the very end. Those are the methods you can call through the appearance proxy. I'm not aware of a list outside of the headers.

The appearance customization is called immediately after passing through the proxy, as well as whenever a new object is constructed. But this will only work for methods marked with that `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR`

Comment: What do you mean by "after passing threw the proxy"? I tried to change the appearance after pressing a button which didn't resolve in the change. After passing in another view and coming back the changes were applied. So I started to believe the changes are done when the view hierarchy was changed or the layout methods are called.

Answer (score 1):

a: The following line

```
 [[UITableView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Will make every table view blue! Just tested on iOS 5 simulator.

b:  The UIAppearance should work on every property on a `UIView`. All the subclasses of `UIView` conforms to `UIAppearance Protocol`

c: I think that the most of will create an class and or method that will customize the appearance and will call it in:

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

Something like: `[ApplicationAppearance setApplicationSchemaTo:ASchemaBlue];`

Edit:

> For example, UIBarButtonItem defines these methods:
>
> @property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor *tintColor UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;

From [UIAppearanceContainer Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/UIAppearanceContainer_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

And in the [UIBarButtonItem Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIBarButtonItem/tintColor) the tintColor is defined

> @property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *tintColor

But in the UIBarButtonItem.h is defined:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor *tintColor __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_5_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
```

I think that the docs are not up to date.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on setBackgroundColor working within this system. It isn't marked as a UI_APPERANCE_SELECTOR in the docs and can break at any time.

Comment: I think that the doc are not updated. I will edit and explain why.

Comment: In the UITableView YES you are write and also in the UIView there are no UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR

Comment: a) That's weird, it's not working for me. With this line I only get the background color in blue for the table view where it was called.

Comment: c) no. I was able to change the appearance after `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` was called by placing the statement in a different view which was presented at runtime. After releasing this view I saw the changes made threw appearance in every other view

Comment: That is what is suppose to do. To change all the classes in your app. To change only one class appearance you should use [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[yourCustomClass class], nil] setTintColor:myNavBarColor];