# Change "System" font in XCode / XIB

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xib

When I create a new control (i.e. a `UILabel`) in XCode 4.2, it defaults the label to Helevtica.

Can anyone tell me where this is set (I'm assuming when it says "System" font, it means for Xcode as a whole, or my entire OS).

And is this something that can be overridden for the whole Application. i.e. changing the setting will update all controls set to "System".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the `UIAppearance` protocol. You can use it to define UI settings for whole classes. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257556/ios-5-curious-about-uiappearance).