# iOS: Using UIAppearance to define custom UITableViewCell color

Tags: ios, uitableview

If I set the backgroundColor attribute on a grouped UITableViewCell, the background color successfully changes. Great.

But I'd like to use UIAppearance to change the background color on all my UITableViewCells, so I can do it in one place and affect a change everywhere. Here's my code:

```
[[UITableViewCell appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:30.0/255.0 green:30.0/255.0 blue:30.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

UITableViewCell implements UIAppearance and UIAppearanceContainer, so I would have thought this would work. But it doesn't. I've also tried using `-[UITableViewCell appearanceWhenContainedIn:(Class)]`, and that doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

*Update (2013/7/8) - This has been fixed in newer versions of iOS. However, it's worth knowing about if you're targeting iOS 6 or below.*

You can blame Apple for this one, and it's actually pretty mean of them. *Technically*, `backgroundColor` **is not customizable** through appearance proxies.

From Apple's documentation:

> To support appearance customization, a class must conform to the UIAppearanceContainer protocol and relevant accessor methods must be marked with UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR.

If we go into a class like `UIBarButtonItem` and look at the `tintColor` property we see this:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIColor *tintColor UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
```

So because it's marked with the `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` tag we know it works with `UIAppearance`.

Here's where Apple are particularly mean: in a `UIView`, `backgroundColor` **has no appearance selector tag, but still works with `UIAppearance`**. According to all the documentation Apple provide it should not, but yet it does!

This gives the misleading impression that it will work for all sub-classes of `UIView`, including `UITableView`. This has come up before, [in this previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257556/ios-5-curious-about-uiappearance)

So the bottom line is that `backgroundColor` shouldn't work at all with `UIAppearance`, but for some reason it does on a `UIView`. It is not guaranteed to work on `UIView` subclasses, and it doesn't work at all on `UITableView`. Sorry I couldn't give you a more positive answer!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I would probably have spent a few hours nodding my head against the wall because of this.

Comment: If this is something that really bothers you (it bothers me!), definitely file a bug report with Apple. I don't think it's really a 'bug' per se, but it's definitely a deficiency. I think I may even have seen someone from Apple use `setBackgroundColor` in a code demo once on appearance proxies.

Comment: @lxt: I am looking at iOS 7 and don't see that it was fixed. Can you please send me an email (my email in address) to discuss. I understand that iOS 7 is still under NDA, so you don't want to put here information, until it's available.

Comment: @VictorRonin - are you looking at the `UITableViewCell` header file?

Comment: @lxt: Yes. And there is only thing which is marked by UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR (it's not a background).

Comment: You can add add UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR using a category, but don't. Mysterious things will happen, since UITableviewCells are used on controls that might surprise you, like pickers! Been there done that.

Answer (score 17):

You can create your own subclass of UITableViewCell that conforms to UIAppearance and mark a custom setter with UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR. Then set the cell backgroundColor on the superlass from your custom setter .

In your appDelegate

```
[[CustomCell appearance] setBackgroundCellColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

In your UItableView subclass

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell <UIAppearance>

@property (nonatomic, weak) UIColor *backgroundCellColor UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
```

---

```
@implementation CustomCell

@synthesize backgroundCellColor;

-(void)setBackgroundCellColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor
{
    [super setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];
}
```

I'm using ARC in this example.

Comment: Even without subclassing, you can use a category and custom properties to proxy appearance calls. It can be useful if you want to theme a part where you can't use a subclass (like for the `UIPrintInteractionController` for example).

Answer (score 3):

***Without Subclassing*!** Doing this on a subclass is probably NOT the best practice, especially if you want to hit all tableView backgrounds. That's a lot of subclassing. A lot of potential bugs. A mess really. The best way to do this is to use a category. You will have to set one up for both the tableViewCell and the tableView. I will just demonstrate the one for the cell. The property on the tableView you must do is the backgroundColor property. NB. I'm prepending my methods with "sat".

// .h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UITableViewCell (Appearance)<UIAppearance>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIColor *satBackgroundColor UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
@end
```

// .m

```
#import "UITableViewCell+Appearance.h"

@implementation UITableViewCell (Appearance)

- (UIColor *)satBackgroundColor
{
    return self.backgroundColor;
}

- (void)setSatBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)satBackgroundColor
{
    self.backgroundColor = satBackgroundColor;
}


@end
```

Now in your appDelegate or some manager class you'll import the category and just call it as if it had an appearance proxy built in.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [UITableViewCell appearance];
cell.satBackgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
```

Ok, so now just do the one for the tableView's background property. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

I used category for this. Below is the sample code
In your .h file write

```
*@interface UITableViewCell (MyCustomCell)
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIColor *backgroundCellColor UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
@end*
```

In your .m file write

```
*@dynamic backgroundCellColor;
-(void)setBackgroundCellColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor
{
    [super setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];
}*
```

It worked well for me. :)
Thanks Nate!!!