# Change the selected cell background colour using UIAppearance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicolor, uiappearance

I need to change the selected cell background colour for all the cells in my app. As I know there is a way to use `UIAppearance` protocol for this purposes. Is it possible to realize this by the category for `UITableViewCell`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this direct to UITableViewCell, but you can do it for its `contentView`:

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewCell class], nil] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Note that it will change all the subViews bg color.

Another option is writing a category or subclass the `UITableViewCell` with `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` mark, check this question:

[iOS: Using UIAppearance to define custom UITableViewCell color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316543/ios-using-uiappearance-to-define-custom-uitableviewcell-color)

Comment: This appears to change all cell background, regardless of selected state or not.

Comment: This looks nice, but can you use `UIAppearance` for only the **selected** state of a `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: @CliftonLabrum I added an answer below that might answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

Using appearance proxy you can colour all cells. Don't know if you can target specific category.

To do the colouring put following code in your AppDelegate.m file:

Put `[self customCellBackground];` 
in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

and somewhere at the end:

```
- (void)customCellBackground {
UIView *cellBackgroundView =[[UIView alloc] init];
cellBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[[UITableViewCell appearance] setSelectedBackgroundView:cellBackgroundView];}
```

Comment: Wouldn't recommend chucking stuff like this into the AppDelegate. At least wrap it in a class which handles global styling and let the AppDelegate call that on startup.

Answer (score 3):

As [null](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1262634/null)'s answer is **not for selected cell backgrounds** and [Armands L.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2202789/armands-l)'s answer **did not work consistently** for me (selecting cells by 'user-tap' did work, but programmatical cell selection showed strange results (like sometimes the selected background was not visible, or did not fill the cell's height properly...).

I found a custom solution that worked:

1. Subclass `UITableViewCell`
2. Initialize `self.selectedBackgroundView` in `init` and
3. Add custom `UIColor` property with `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` for custom selected background color

`.h` file:

```
@property (nonatomic) UIColor* selectedCellBackgroundColor UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
```

`.m` file:

in `init` method(s):

`self.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];`

and last but not least the setter function for the color:

```
- (void) setSelectedCellBackgroundColor:(UIColor*) color {
    _selectedCellBackgroundColor = color;
    self.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = color;
}
```