# UICollectionViewCell drawing shadow and bound

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, uiappearance

I have a code for drawing bounds to UICollectionViewCell. It works when I call it in "cellForItemAtIndexPath".

```
[cell.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
[cell.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[cell.layer setCornerRadius:7.5f];
[cell.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
[cell.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
[cell.layer setShadowRadius:8.0];
[cell.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8];
```

But what I want to do is implement this features in appDelegate so I don't have to implement all this code to various classes.

```
[[[UICollectionViewCell appearance] layer] setMasksToBounds:NO];
[[[UICollectionViewCell appearance] layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
[[[UICollectionViewCell appearance] layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[[[UICollectionViewCell appearance] layer] setCornerRadius:7.5f];
[[[UICollectionViewCell appearance] layer] setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
[[[UICollectionViewCell appearance] layer] setShadowColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
[[[UICollectionViewCell appearance] layer] setShadowRadius:8.0];
[[[UICollectionViewCell appearance] layer] setShadowOpacity:0.8];
```

When I use above code in appDelegate it doesn't work. Any suggestion??

I also import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of those properties (the CALayer properties) supported the appearance proxy.

Have a look at [this list for all the properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9424142/608157) that can be styled using the appearance proxy.

Comment: What is the best way to achieve this goal? I really don't want to add all this code to number of class.

Comment: You could subclass UICollectionViewCell to make your own cell that has the correct layout, subviews and visual properties