# setBackgroundView appearance for UITableView causes endless loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios5, uiappearance

I faced strange endless loop in some cases using setBackgroundView for UITableView appearance. Here is  appearance initialization:

```c
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"bg"]];
[[UITableView appearance] setBackgroundView:iv];
```

I have a controller:

```c
@interface MyController : UITableViewController
```

that has only `init` method and `viewWill*/viewDid*` delegates with simple logging. Nothing else. In such case I'm getting endless messages about layouting subviews:

```
2013-06-05 21:23:45.054 MyApp[16700:c07] init
2013-06-05 21:23:45.056 MyApp[16700:c07] viewDidLoad
2013-06-05 21:23:45.057 MyApp[16700:c07] viewWillAppear
2013-06-05 21:23:46.059 MyApp[16700:c07] viewWillLayoutSubviews
2013-06-05 21:23:47.061 MyApp[16700:c07] viewDidLayoutSubviews
2013-06-05 21:23:48.064 MyApp[16700:c07] viewWillLayoutSubviews
2013-06-05 21:23:49.066 MyApp[16700:c07] viewDidLayoutSubviews
2013-06-05 21:23:50.067 MyApp[16700:c07] viewWillLayoutSubviews
2013-06-05 21:23:51.069 MyApp[16700:c07] viewDidLayoutSubviews
2013-06-05 21:23:52.070 MyApp[16700:c07] viewWillLayoutSubviews
```

If I'll switch to:

```c
@interface MyController : UIViewController
```

everything is going well.

Is this expected behavior (and I didn't understood UIAppearance clearly) or this is broken functionality?

**UPD**: appearance initialized in AppDelegate.

**UPD2**: endless loop happens only on table view controllers that are pushed from another one

Comment: When / where are you modifying the appearance?

Comment: @Wain Looks like appdelegate, to me.

Comment: Yes, I do this in appdelegate.

Comment: Hmm.... I pasted your code into my app delegate, and I didn't get any infinite loop. The appearance was changed correctly.

Comment: I do get the endless loop though if I try to push from the first table view controller to another one.

Comment: IMO this seems like a bug in `UITableViewController` if this isn't happening with simple `UITableView` instances in `UIViewController`

Comment: @RyanPoolos, I agree, this looks like a bug. Easy to get around though -- just set the backgroundView in the viewDidLoad method of your tableViewController(s).

Comment: @rdelmar I started to share my code, but you was faster. :) Yes, I also have a loop only with pushed table view controller. I'll update my question with this note.

Comment: I noticed that this has to do with the animation of the transition. If I switch to a modal transition and uncheck the "Animates" box, I don't get the infinite loop (I do get it with a modal using any of the transition styles except flip horizontal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424112/what-properties-can-i-set-via-an-uiappearance-proxy/9424142#9424142) `UITableView` doesn't support appearance customization using `setBackgroundView`. So this isn't a bug - it simply unsupported yet.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple documentation, [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has a background property.

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BackgroundImage.png"]];
```

Setting an image as the background of a UITableView is possible, albeit slight convoluted. There are four steps:

1) Set the backgroundColor property of your tableView to clearColor, so that the background image is visible.

```
[myTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

2) Create an instance of a UIImageView and set its image property to the image that you want to appear behind the table.

```
UIImageView *tableBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"]];
```

3) Set the UIImageView’s frame property so that it’s the same size as that of the tableView:

```
[tableBackgroundView setFrame: myTableView.frame];
```

4) Update the tableView’s backgroundImage property to point to your new UIImageView object:

```
[myTableView setBackgroundView:tableBackgroundView];
```

Comment: I used same approach earlier, before I have switched to iOS 5 UIAppearance. Once I switched, I faced with setBackgorundView issues, using UIAppearance. So my question concerns UIAppearance. But seems there is no right solution for UIAppearance, so your answer could be used as workaround. Thanks.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are looking to have a custom background image for your table. If so, why are you using UIAppearance to accomplish this?

Comment: I have no requirements for my app about UIAppearance approach, I simply decided to try newer API, since it simplier and doesn't require straight subclassing of everything.