# Set rounded corners globally on UIButtons in iOS application

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiappearance

Is there a way to set UIButtons with rounded corners globally like with color below?

```
[[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Add this in your header file.

then in implementation,

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100,50);
[btn setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:128.0/255.0f green:0.0/255.0f  blue:0.0/255.0f alpha:0.7]];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 120.0, 50.0);//width and height should be same  value
btn.clipsToBounds = YES;

btn.layer.cornerRadius = 20;//half of the width
btn.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
btn.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;
```

cornerRadius will do the trick for you.. Let me know if more info needed.. :)

**Edit**

This cannot be achieved globally. As you used `appearence`, [here is the list](https://gist.github.com/mattt/5135521) to see what you can customize with `UIAppearance`. what you can do is you can create a subclass of your UIButton, & there you can write implementation of `setCornerRadius` in `initWithCoder` Method.

Comment: I already know about `btn.layer.cornerRadius`, but I want to set it globally with one line of code.  Yours creates a button each time.

Comment: Hey i didn't understood why downvote for me? i've written the same thing what Colin has said

Comment: It *can* be achieved with a category or extension which adds custom property/ies on `UIButton` because the prototype `appearance` object is copied using KV semantics.

Answer (score 3):

The list of properties that you can set using UIAppearance is found here:

[What properties can I set via an UIAppearance proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424112/what-properties-can-i-set-via-an-uiappearance-proxy)

Unfortunately rounded corners are not something that is possible.

You could use something like beautify (https://github.com/beautify/beautify-ios) which enhances the UIKit controls to allow you to specify rounded buttons.

With beautify, the following would give you rounded buttons globally:

```
BYTheme *theme = [BYTheme new];
theme.buttonStyle.border = [[BYBorder alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor blackColor]
                                                     width:2.0f
                                                    radius:5.0f];

[[BYThemeManager instance] applyTheme:theme];
```

Comment: I get a warning in Xcode at `theme.buttonStyle.border` -  Instance method '-initWithColor:width:radius:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Answer (score 1):

I've found this link. Please see if it could help.

[Taming UIButton](http://www.popculturesoft.com/post/Taming-the-UIButton.aspx)

It is using this

```
[[basicButton layer] setCornerRadius:18.0f];
```

As i mentioned in previous answer. You have to subclass UiButton for it.. :)

Comment: it isn't necessarily Mike Flynn who downvoted you. It could have been anyone! That's just the way it is with StackOverflow.

Comment: Yeah sorry.. First downvote for me till now.. lost 2 reputation.. It hurts ..:P

Comment: Don't worry about it - I've just upvoted you to give you 10 back :-)

Comment: I didnt downvote anyone, you had a legit answer just not the one I was hoping for.

Comment: @Mike.. Sorry.. Sometimes I am really weird. Anyhow, i took my words back from the answer. :|

Answer (score 0):

Migrating advice for a workable solution to Swift (it's also possible using an equivalent ObjC category on UIView):

### 1. Add this extension https://gist.github.com/d3ce2e216884541217d0

### 2. Code:

```
let a = UIButton.appearance()
a.layerCornerRadius = 20.0
a.layerBorderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
a.layerBorderWidth = 2.0
```

This sort of hack works because of how properties are copied.  All `appearance` changes to things like `a.layer` and `a.titleLabel` are not propagated, but extension properties *are copied*.