# UIAppearance changing UITableView backgroundView crashes main thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiappearance

I have created a tiny little project to show what is happening.

You can get it from [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/oliverfoggin/crashing-table-appearance).

As a brief explanation.

I have an app that I want to use an image as the background view of several `UITableViews`.

At first I was setting it every time I created a `UITableView` and it was working fine but felt like a lot of repetition.

So I moved it into a `UIAppearance` update.

However, now there are certain things that cause the main thread to block and the memory rockets.

If you download my repo you'll be able to see what's going on.

Is there something I can do to get this working? Or is this a bug with iOS?

I'm looking at setting it all up per table view again :D

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424112/what-properties-can-i-set-via-an-uiappearance-proxy/9424142#9424142) UITableView doesn't support appearance customization using setBackgroundView. So this isn't a bug - it simply unsupported yet.