# How to make the background of all UITextViews Purple without subclassing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitextview, swizzling

I have an app that I want to debug. I'd like every UITextview within the app to have a purple background.

I think method swizzling is a possible solution, but I have not been able to get this to work.

**Question:** How can I do this without subclassing or manually setting each textview's background color?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
[[UITextView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
```

The appearance proxy was introduced in iOS5 as a convenient way for styling core UIKit classes without subclassing. It can be used in a variety of really useful ways such as setting a UINavigationBar's tint color, button tints, etc.

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful. I never knew about:[UITextView appearance].
It doesnt seem to work with Textview's though :( 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424112/what-properties-can-i-set-via-an-uiappearance-proxy

Comment: Have you tried it on iOS 7.1? I just gave it a shot and it worked as expected, all my text views were infact purple. Let me know if it's not working on other versions.