# change tint and background colors of a ABPeoplePickerNavigationController embedded in a tab bar view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, abpeoplepickerview

i have a tab bar controller in witch i would like to embed a ABPeoplePickerNavigationController. I' done so by putting this code in viewDidLoad

```
[super viewDidLoad];
_addressBookController = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
[_addressBookController setDelegate:self];
[_addressBookController setPeoplePickerDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:_addressBookController.view];
```

my problem is that i would like to uniform the ABPeople controller to my app bgcolor and tint, but actually i'm only able to change the title of the navigation controller via the method below

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animated
```

can some help me to change all colors and tints?

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 0):

You can change the style of the *ABPeoplePickerNavigationController* using the `appearanceWhenContainedIn` method (iOS > 5). Remember to do your customization before loading the view controller.

Here an example:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class], nil] setBarTintColor:[UIColor yourColor]];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor yourColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor yourColor], NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont yourFont]}]; //navigation bar title
[[UISearchBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class], nil] setBarTintColor:[UIColor yourColor]];
[[UITableView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class], nil] setSectionIndexColor:[UIColor yourColor]];
[[UITableViewHeaderFooterView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class], nil] setTintColor:yourColor];
```

If you want a full list of what properties you can change, you can look at this question: [What properties can I set via an UIAppearance proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424112/what-properties-can-i-set-via-an-uiappearance-proxy/9424142#9424142)