# UITextField customization in AppDelegate not working for Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, appdelegate

I want to customise all the textFields at once via AppDelegate , I had tested the customisation working on individual ViewControllers but when I add the customisation through AppDelegate then it does not appears. Please guide me for what have I missed :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    UITextField.appearance().layer.borderWidth = 2
    UITextField.appearance().layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.094 , green:0.737 ,  blue:0.612 ,  alpha:1).CGColor
           return true
}
```

Comment: try to subclass UITextField

Comment: yes you were right  , it worked for me @NANNAV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution , thanx to @nannav.
Rather than customising the TextField in AppDelegate, we should create a new class like :

```
class MyCustomTextField: UITextField {
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.layer.borderWidth = 2
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.094 , green:0.737 ,  blue:0.612 ,  alpha:1).CGColor
}
```

}

later in storyBoard we have to assign **MyCustomTextField** in customClass to the Textfields we wanted to customise

Answer (score 1):

`UITextField` is not tagged with UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR so this is the reason why it does not work like `UITextField.appearance()...`.

For more info, look at [What properties can I set via an UIAppearance proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424112/what-properties-can-i-set-via-an-uiappearance-proxy)