# How can I change the color of the UITableView for the entire application?

Tags: swift, uitableview

How can I change the color of the UITableView for the entire application?

Currently I have this set in some of my controllers but it does not work for some parts of the tableview.

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.20, green:0.22, blue:0.29, alpha:1.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIAppearance` does not support to change the background color of tableview in globally, you need to create the **extension** that inherits from UITableView, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9424142/817946) is a link to an answer containing a list of all methods supported by `UIAppearance`.

for e.g

```
extension UITableView {

 func setBGforTable(){
let divideCount: CGFloat = 255.0
self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.20/divideCount, green:0.22/divideCount, blue:0.29/divideCount, alpha:1.0)

}
}
```

and call the method in your VC as

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad() 
    yourtableViewName.setBGforTable()
  }
```

Comment: Why is tblActivity not being recognized?

Comment: Strange question, I don't think my tableView has a name, what would I put there instead?

Comment: if you are used the tablevieewcontroller then use `self.tableView.setBGforTable()`

Comment: Now it says my controller "has no member 'setBGforTable'

Comment: create the `extension UITableView {` in your app, then its called automatically

Comment: Thank you so much!