# Objective C - Change System Font with Category

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, autolayout

I want to change the default font for all **UITextViews**. It seems that the easiest way to do this is via **custom category**. I found this solution: [Change the default systemFont used by controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13798450/change-the-default-systemfont-used-by-controls) and tried to implement it.

But my UITextViews are added programmatically so the awakeFromNib function is not called. I tried to move it to initWithFrame like this:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    id result = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (result) {
        float size = [self.font pointSize];
        NSString *stringfontstyle=self.font.fontName;
        if([stringfontstyle rangeOfString:@"Bold"].location != NSNotFound) {
            self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Black" size:size];
        }
        else if ([stringfontstyle rangeOfString:@"Italic"].location != NSNotFound) {
            self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Oblique" size:size];
        }
        else if ([stringfontstyle rangeOfString:@"Medium"].location != NSNotFound) {
            self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Medium" size:size];
        }
        else {
            self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Roman" size:size];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Weird is that if my category contains initWithFrame function, the UITextView disappears. What is it that I'm missing?

Note: I'm using **autoLayout** so the initWithFrame is called with CGRectZero, but I suppose that isn't the problem.

**EDIT:**

The problem is that the font is null when the UITextView is initiated. So what method would be appropriate to place the code into?

Comment: You appear to have subclassing and categories mixed-up.  Consider what `super` is in the code you post.  I am pretty sure you cannot override methods using a category.

Comment: So I should make a UITextView subclass and override the setFont function?

Comment: @trojanfoe by the looks of it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272451/overriding-methods-using-categories-in-objective-c) you can override methods using categories but it is discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when category contains a method, it overrides the class's method... and thats not good. subclassing would work.. method swizzling might be a way but...

why don't you just subclass UITextView - then you can keep your initWithFrame thingy or maybe override font

```
- (UIFont*)font {
   if(!myFont) {
      _myFont = xy;
   }

   id superFont = super.font;
   if(![superFont.name isEqualTo:_myFont.name]) {
       super.font = [myFont fontWithSize:superFont.pointSize];
   }
   return _myFont;
}
```

or setFont:

```
- (void)setFont:(UIFont*)newFont {
   if(!myFont) {
      _myFont = xy;
   }

   id thisFont = [_myFont fontWithSize:newFont.pointSize];
   super.font = thisFont;
```

Comment: UIAppearance is great but I guess it would be impossible to incorporate with things like size classes right?

Comment: of course - you could also change setFont ;) written out it might be nicer :D

Comment: Thank for all your help. I have overridden the setFont method and it works great.